# Is it possible to include one select in another?

Tags: xml, mybatis, ibatis

I have 2 selects mapper methods :

- selectOne
- selectTwo

I want to include these statements to selectThree method as below.

Is it possible to include one select in another? And if yes, then how?

```
<mapper>
...
    <select id="selectOne" resultMap="mytype">
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            mytype
    </select>

    <select id="selectTwo" resultMap="mytype">
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            mytype
    </select>

    <select id="selectThree" resultMap="mytype">
        <include refid="selectOne" />
        UNION
        <include refid="selectTwo" />
    </select>
...
</mapper>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do it with `<select>` tag but you if your intention is to have a reusable code, you could use `<sql>` tag instead.

```
<sql id="selectOne">
    SELECT * FROM mytype
</sql>
```

Please refer to the [document](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#sql) for more details.